# Qlik Sense Extension - Get variable value

Tags: qliksense

How to get the value of a variable defined in qlik sense in an extension written in java script?

I tried it but it did not work for me

```
require(["js/qlik"], function(qlik) {
  //open the app
  var app = qlik.openApp('c31e2aba-3b46-4b13-8b87-c5c2514dea1d', config);
  //get the variable content
  app.variable.getContent('MYVAR',function ( reply ){
    alert( JSON.stringify( reply ) );
  });
});
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I guess you have copied the script from the [Qlik help page](https://help.qlik.com/en-US/sense-developer/June2019/Subsystems/APIs/Content/Sense_ClientAPIs/CapabilityAPIs/VariableAPI/getContent-variable-method.htm).

You first need to substitute the app id "c31e2aba-3b46-4b13-8b87-c5c2514dea1d" with the id of your app.

Then you need a variable in that app called MYVAR. (Or change your script, to match a variable you have.)

Comment: I writed it with my details and its not worded.

Comment: Well in that case you need to give us some more information. Because the snippet looks correct.  Do you get any error messages in the DevTools (F12) Console? Errors in the Network tab? What is the rest of the js? (You need to configure the required object.) Did you start from scratch, or did you use Qlik's Mashup in Dev-Hub? Is this page on the Qlik server, or another we server (i.e. do the use the same hostname or not)